# Retrofit call.enqueue method not being called

Tags: java, android

MasterService.java

```java
// MasterService.java


    public interface MasterService {

    @GET("userMaster")
    Call<List<UserMaster>> getUsers();

    @GET("farmerMaster")
    Call<List<FarmerMaster>> getfarmers();

    @GET("orgnMaster")
    Call<List<OrgnMaster>> getOrgns();

    @GET("cropMaster")
    Call<List<CropMaster>> getCrops();

    @POST("farmerPost")
    Call<FarmerMaster> createPost(@Body FarmerMaster farmerMaster);

}
```

MasterRepository.java

````java
// MasterRepository.java

    public class MasterRepository {


    MasterDao masterDao;


    MasterService masterService;
    List<UserMaster> userMasters;
    List<FarmerMaster> farmerMasters;
    List<CropMaster> cropMasters;
    List<OrgnMaster> orgnMasters;

    /**
    *  Constructor
    *  @param application application context
     * Get the instance of AppDatabase(Local database) and Retrofit(Service)
    * */
    public MasterRepository(Application application) {



        Retrofit retrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.50/MEPLSERVICES/API/")
                .build();

        masterService =retrofit.create(MasterService.class);

    }


    /**
    * @return All the UserMaster info as a List
    *  */


    public List<UserMaster> getUserMasters(){

        try {

            Call<List<UserMaster>> call = masterService.getUsers();


            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserMaster>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<UserMaster>> call, Response<List<UserMaster>> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    List<UserMaster> userMasters = response.body();
                    for(UserMaster userMaster:userMasters){
                        System.out.println(userMaster);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<UserMaster>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+e);
        }

        return userMasters;
    }



    }


// While hitting the Url http://192.168.1.50/MEPLSERVICES/API/userMaster, i get the json request as follows

```javascript  



 [{"empID":"1","empName":"admin","empType":"admin","password":"admin","fullName":"Anandaraj","designation":"administator","department":"admin","empCode":"10001","mobileNumber":"8939803008","emailAddress":"admin@admin.com"},{"empID":"35","empName":"h","empType":"Admin","password":"s","fullName":"s","designation":"Manager","department":"Marketing","empCode":"xy12","mobileNumber":"345","emailAddress":"est@test.com"}]
````

** When i call `getUserMasters` method of `MasterRepository` Class , `call.enqueue` not being called..

Dependencies
  //RetroFit

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: add some logs to your onFailure and !response.isSuccessful() block and see what happens

Comment: and please add this interceptor to your client to see more logs: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: print the log in `onFailure` method.